# Avoiding a NullPointerException

Tags: java

```
String graphNameUsed = graphName.getName();
        if (graphType.equals("All") || graphType.equals("ALL"))
            graphNameUsed += "_ALL";
```

If my String is null, then will it throw `NullPointerException` when I am checking whether it equals or not. To avoid this exception, how should I check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flip the comparisons the other way around so you're calling `equals()` on the string literals, which aren't null and thus won't cause the exception.

When null is passed to the `equals()` method, it simply returns `false` right away. However, if you try to call it on a variable that's null, the object isn't there for you to call that method on, which is why you get the exception.

```
if ("All".equals(graphType) || "ALL".equals(graphType))
```

If you just want to do case-insensitive matches, use the `equalsIgnoreCase()` method instead so you just perform one check:

```
if ("All".equalsIgnoreCase(graphType))
```

Comment: How do u say my code can throw null pointer expection and why not this code you have written will not throw?

Comment: is there any better way to handle such expections... i mean via expection handling

Comment: @John: The solution we've provided is much better than placing a `catch (NullPointerException e)`. Prevention is better than cure.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
if("All".equals(graphType) || "ALL".equals(graphType))
```

And you can take advantage of short-circuiting with something like:

```
if(graphType != null && (graphType.equals("All") || graphType.equals("ALL")))
```

Comment: Note: `==` compares references, not values.